# BitBucket Connection Timed Out

Tags: laravel, bitbucket

I cloned a repository from bitbucket and it has the following json in `composer.json`.

```
"repositories": [
{
   "type": "git",
   "url": "ssh://git@192.168.x.xxx:xxxx/xyz/somefile.git"
 },
 {
   "type": "git",
   "url": "ssh://git@192.168.x.xxx:xxxx/xyz/somefile.git"
 }
],
```

But when I try to install or update composer it gives me the following error.

> [RuntimeException]
>     Failed to execute git clone --mirror .....
>     ssh: connect to host 192.168.x.xxxx port xxxx: Connection timed out
>     fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>     Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>     and the repository exists.

I am fairly new to bitbucket so I am not sure if its the problem at my end but I am logging in from the account that has access to the repository.

Comment: Do you have any Git server running at `192.168.x.xxx:xxxx`?

Comment: Yes I found the solution thank you. The person didn't sent me these modules. I had to ask them separately.